# Change of state to make button enable from disabled postion in react js

Tags: reactjs

i have this finish button in my child class ...
im trying to change the state of the disabling button when the finish button is clicked

```
{currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1 && (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        this.finishQuiz();
        this.pushtoDB2();
        //  this.disableCheckLevel();
        this.props.handleDisableValue(scores); // child to parent
      }}
    >
      Finish
    </Button>
)}
```

i have 4 buttons to change state to false onclick of finish button to enable clicking.
i have a rookie button,sutdent,intermediate,expert,master button.
but i want to change the state in that order.
say if I'm on rookie i can only enable student when rookie is enabled and the score >=5
then student is enabled. then intermediate is enabled if student is enabled and scores>=5 else stays in the same state. this goes until master button
Issue I'm having is that mine goes from rookie to student but doesn't move any further.

this is the  logic i used for disabling state

```
disabledRook: true,
disabledStudent: true,
disabledInterm: true,
disabledExpert: true,
disabledMaster: true,
```

//intiall state value

```
handleDisableValue = scores => {
    if (this.state.disabledRook && scores >= 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledStudent: false
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledStudent === false && scores >= 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledInterm: false
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledInterm === false && scores >= 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledExpert: false
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledExpert === false && scores >= 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledMaster: false
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledRook && scores < 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledRook: true
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledStudent && scores < 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledStudent: true
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledInterm && scores < 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledInterm: true
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledExpert && scores < 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledExpert: true
      });
    } else if (this.state.disabledMaster && scores < 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledMaster: true
      });
    }
```

This is where i call the states in the buttons i created

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    this.changeToquiz1();
    this.articelState();
  }}
>
  Rookie
</Button>
<Button
  disabled={this.state.disabledStudent}
  onClick={() => {
    this.articelState();
    this.changeToquiz2();
  }}
>
  Student
</Button>
<Button
  disabled={this.state.disabledInterm}
  onClick={() => {
    this.changeToquiz3();
    this.articelState();
  }}
>
  Intermediate
</Button>
<Button
  disabled={this.state.disabledExpert}
  onClick={() => {
    this.changeToquiz4();
    this.articelState();
  }}
>
  Expert
</Button>
<Button
  disabled={this.state.disabledMaster}
  onClick={() => {
    this.changeToquiz5();
    this.articelState();
  }}
>
  Master
</Button>
```

Any help thanks

Comment: Please clarify problem / help needed.

Comment: @realAlexBarge i have above..Issue I'm having is that mine goes from rookie to student(enabled state) but doesn't move any further. like intermidiate,expert etc stops on on student

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with too many if else after studnent level it will go in wrong condition. I have another solution for your problem instead of many boolean just keep one state like level and just increase level once player score more than 5 points.

```
const STUDENT = 1;
const INTERN = 2;
const EXPERT =3;
const MASTER =4;

state = {
  level: 0
}
handleDisableValue(score) {
  if(score > 5 && this.state.level < 4) {
    this.setState(prevState=> ({ level: prevState.level + 1 }));
  }
}
```

In your button:

```
<Button
 onClick={() => {
   this.changeToquiz1();
   this.articelState();
 }}
>
 Rookie
</Button>
<Button
 disabled={this.state.level < STUDENT}
 onClick={() => {
   this.articelState();
   this.changeToquiz2();
 }}
>
 Student
</Button>
<Button
 disabled={this.state.level < INTERN}
 onClick={() => {
   this.changeToquiz3();
   this.articelState();
 }}
>
 Intermediate
</Button>
<Button
 disabled={this.state.level < EXPERT}
 onClick={() => {
   this.changeToquiz4();
   this.articelState();
 }}
>
 Expert
</Button>
<Button
 disabled={this.state.level < MASTER}
 onClick={() => {
   this.changeToquiz5();
   this.articelState();
 }}
>
 Master
</Button>
```

I Have made working codesandbox with next level button this you should call once quiz is complete i used it just for demo purpose.

[image: Edit enable-disable-level]

Comment: this.state.level < EXPERT returns a boolean @dave

Comment: @Donzen when i used this code it enabled all the buttons as it was false so something is wrong with this

Comment: @dave i have updated answer and added working codesandbox url.

Comment: Ok its working...also im trying to get the value sent to database for the level do that when user logs in he is already in the latest level rather than re doing all the levels again...would u know how should i assign the value from DB to the level:0?

Comment: you can map DB value to your javascript level values. for eg. if your DB has a level as "student" you can use state value to STUDENT constant which is 1. you can create a simple object like `{ "student": STUDENT, "master": MASTER, and other }` and get current level and assign that to your state.

Comment: @AmitChauhan can u do an example of what u said above if u dont mind because i have the level value in db and have it retrieved but dont know how to assign it

Comment: can tell me what are values in your database?

Comment: @dave what problem are you facing here? it should be fairly easy with react's lifecycle method to setState from your rank value. if you can show me code how are you getting api in codesandbox then i can help you there.

Comment: @dave that's so much of code and i am confused. basically you need to pass your rank value to your component and update that value in state, read about react's lifecycle methods.

Comment: @AmitChauhan i have a new issue the above one is fixed...see for the level say if we have passed all the way to expert level but u want to redo level student again and if the user scores >5 they pass but the levelling up doesnt move past expert level as they havent attended expert level quiz yet...how do i approach this part

Comment: you can pass quiz level to your function and check if quizLevel === this.sate.leave then only increase level otherwise don't increase level.